# How to run and install EXE file from the web browser using JS without user approve

Tags: javascript, clickonce, exe

I want to implement in my website a functionality like in google chrome website, that a user click on a website form and the file will auto download and install itself without any user approve or interferance.
Here is the google chrome website: https://www.google.com/chrome/index.html?hl=iw

I know that they use clickonce technology by ms for IE and oneclick technology by google for all other browsers, but there is a way that i can also use thier code and their technology to run my own files?
I know they also use google update task that runs on windows background but I dont know how to use it with my own files.

Comment: If this is possible then its a security threat. Anyone can install anything on my computer without my permission.

Comment: I know, but, is it possible by using google update or they block files by domain?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this functionality is possible only if the client has .NET Framework (version 4 I guess), and your domain is in the trusted domains list of the user's preferences for this functionality. So this would work only on Windows platform, and your domain need to be added to the mentioned list (what is unlikely to happen I guess). A short answer is NO, you can't do this, if you are not a corporation like Google.

Bonus: You don't need it, users do not like to be tricked, they want to know everything that happens with they computer.

Answer (score 1):

For security reason, you cannot access file from your website. What would happen if a user open a website, and they got some programs installed in their machine? That's gonna be serious problem